# How best to define the type of a variable

Tags: typescript

So I accept that my google foo may just have been too weak to find the answer to this already so pointers to documentation would be happily accepted!

I am in the process of turning on strict type checking to an established typescript project.

One of the things I've come up against is how to best assign types to variables that cannot be correctly inferred.

For example, in this case the compiler throws an error because the type of `obj` is inferred as `{}` and cannot be indexed by `string` (please note this is a trivial example to illustrate the problem - I'm not looking for solutions to this specific case)

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
const obj = {};
arr.forEach(item => {
  if (!obj[item]) {
    obj[item] = 0;
  }
  obj[item] += 1;
}
```

What I would like to do here is to strictly type `obj` as a `Record<string, number>` but the compiler throws an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)
```

I've come across two ways to do this:

```
const obj: Record<string, number> = {};
```

or

```
const obj = {} as Record<string, number>;
```

Both result in the typescript engine resolving `obj` to the correct type, but I want to know if there is any difference between the two, and which is considered best practice (and why).

Comment: @kaya3 pretty much yes - thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely the first option:

`const obj: Record<string, number> = {};`

If you get into the habit of this pattern you can ensure that your object has to fit the typing you have specified.

The latter:
`const obj = {} as Record<string, number>;` is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (thanks kaya3) and is not type-safe.

Comment: casting in the 2nd option will also check for types compatibility, but this way is less preferred by the community for sure

Comment: @Andrei A type assertion (it's not a cast) means the compiler will only check compatibility in the sense that either the expression's type is assignable to the asserted type *or the asserted type is assignable to the expressions's type*, but the latter is not type-safe. For example you can write `{} as {x: number}` and there is no error, despite the fact that the object `{}` is not assignable to the type `{x: number}`.